# How to convert and copy files from NTFS to FAT32

Tags: linux, windows, ntfs, fat32

I copied some files edited on Windows to a SD memory which is formatted in Linux OS. ut those files being in ntfs, could not be read by Linux OS. I am looking for a cmd or tool on windows which can convert files to fat32 before copying so that I can rwx on Linux.

Comment: The file system is not the files. Putting the files on a FAT32 storage media would be all the "conversion" you need.

Comment: Linux can read NTFS.  It isn't clear what the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

NTFS and FAT32 are not different *file formats,* they are different *file systems*. The contents of files are independent of the file system. So except for some very technical metadata issues such as which characters are allowed in file names, the maximum length of file names and permission structures there is nothing at all to be done in order to copy or move files from one to the other.